# MySQL: What is the benefit of non-ansi mode?

Tags: mysql, sql, ansi-sql

Because I routinely work with a number of different databases, I make a point of switching MySQL to ANSI mode to bring some consistency into my code. This way I can use double quotes for column names and `||` for concatenation, which is normal for most databases (MSSQL, it appears doesn’t use `||`).

Apart from compatibility, is there a benefit in *not* switching to ANSI mode in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi):

> ANSI
>   Equivalent to REAL_AS_FLOAT, PIPES_AS_CONCAT, ANSI_QUOTES, IGNORE_SPACE, and (as of MySQL 5.7.5) ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

The first four of these included modes are mostly minor cosmetic things, such as allowing pipes for string concatenation, and ignoring spaces between a function name and the `(` character.  From the point of view of porting your MySQL code to another database, these would be an annoyance, but would require fairly minor changes.

However, the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode is a different story.  When this mode is turned *off* in MySQL (which would happen if `ANSI` were disabled), then it means you could have a `GROUP BY` query which selects columns not appearing in aggregates or in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Such a query would likely fail completely on any other database, save perhaps MariaDB.  In addition, if you write all your queries with the laxity of `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode disabled, then you could be faced with a major refactor of many queries if you were to ever try porting your code to another database.

I would advise you to stick to ANSI stanadards.  In the case of `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, adhering to it is just good database practice, and the other minor cosmetic requirements are things you may already be doing.

Comment: Actually, I was unaware of the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` feature until recently, and never used it. I’m actually using MariaDB 10.2, where I presume it is also the default. So, for my purposes, I lose nothing that I needed, and gain in compatible syntax. Thanks.

Comment: I might add that the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` feature only returns a single ungrouped value. This could result in an unreliable answer in a query such as `SELECT id,min(dob) FROM customers` where more than one row might match, and it’s pot-luck which row you get. I am inclined to recommend against it.

Comment: Another significant point is that in traditional mode, MySQL doesn’t have a concatenation operator. There is, of course, the `concat()` function, but not having a simple operator is a pain in the neck.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit long for a comment.  ANSI mode -- which is well-explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-combo) -- is basically a few stylistic changes to the language.  These changes may seem minor, but they go against the grain of the history of MySQL.

In other words, using ANSI mode means that "traditional" MySQL code is not necessarily supported.  Is that good or bad?  Depends.  If you need compatibility with other databases, then it is good.  If you need compatibility with legacy code, then it is bad.